# Firebase in android webview

Tags: firebase, android-webview

I'm making an app that's contained in a WebView. Andorid 5.0 and up. As a database, I want to use firebase. However, requests to firebase say `could not contact database`. Is this expected and is there a way to be able to use firebase in a webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my facepalm.

didn't give app permissions for internet

Solved by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to the manifest.